# Separating unique column to multiple columns in multiple csv files in R

Tags: r, csv, import

im trying to separate a unique column in multiple csv files. I've already done it for one single file with this code:

```
tempmax <- read.csv(file="path", header=TRUE, sep=";", fill = TRUE) 
colnames(tempmax) = c("Fecha", "Hora", "Temperatura max")
rbind(tempmax)
write.csv(tempmax, "path", sep = ";", append = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

However, I haven't found the way to do it in multiple csv saved in a folder. I would like to do the same: read, modify and write the new one.

I used this to read the multiple files:

```
getwd <- ("path")
filenames <- list.files("path", 
                        pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
```

But i just cant find the way to edit what i want. (i'm pretty new using R)
I appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: In your code the `rbind(tempmax)` is doing nothing.  and it is not showing where you are separating unique column in the first block of code

Answer (score 0):

If we have several files, we can use `lapply`.  It is not clear about the transformation.  So, the file is written back by selecting the first column

```
lapply(filenames, function(file){
      tempmax <- read.csv(file= file, header=TRUE, sep=";", fill = TRUE) 
      colnames(tempmax) = c("Fecha", "Hora", "Temperatura max")

      write.csv(tempmax[1], file, sep = ";", append = FALSE,
             row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)})
```

Comment: I applied the code and it it deleted two columns (the second and the third) in all the files. It showed me this error:  Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Comment: @SebastianFallas your code was not clear because  it was not doing anything in the first block of code i.e. just reading and writing the same file.

Comment: I could fix it! Thank you so much for your help!